# Are cyclic dependencies supported in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have seen previous discussions, but thought I'd re-ask the question for newer versions of SBT.

Is there a way to create a cyclical dependency in SBT 0.13+?

Thanks

Comment: sbt wrap ivy. Check ivy documentation.

Comment: what could be a purpose of a cyclic dependency?

Comment: @laughedelic One example I can think of (and am currently investigating) is having a module's test configuration depend on a "testkit" module, while having the testkit depend on the core module's compile config, to be able to use classes from core to implement some of the functionality (domain objects for matchers, builders, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about library dependencies or task dependencies?

If it's library dependencies, we do not recommend it, but underlying resolver engine probably will handle it.

If you're talking about task dependencies, we do not support it.